# How to validate textboxes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and am trying to validate a text-box. Basically, if user inputs less than 2 or a non number how can I get the error to display. Here's the [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/performing-simple-validation-cs) I am trying to follow.

I have my code below.

**Create View:**

```
<%= Html.ValidationSummary()%>
<%= using (HtmlBeginForm()){%>
<div class="half-col">
    <label for="Amount">Amount:</label>
    <%= Html.TextBox("Amount")%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Amount", "*")%>
</div>
```

**Create Controller:**

```
[AcceptVerbs (HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude ="ID")] Charity productToCreate)
{
    //Validation
    if (productToCreate.Amount < 2)
        ModelState.AddModelError("Amount, Greater than 2 please");

    return View(db.Donations.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Take(5).ToList());  //Display 5 recent records from table 
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class Charity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Double Amount { get; set; }
    public Double TaxBonus { get; set; }
    public String Comment { get; set; }
}
```

**Error:**

> CS1501    No overload for method 'AddModelError' takes 1 CharitySite

Comment: In MVC, you do not validate a textbox, you validate a model.  Textboxes are associated with model properties, and if those properties of the model do not validate, then the error is displayed associated with the textbox for that property.

Comment: Why are you following a tutorial from 2009? If you want to learn asp.net MVC, learn the latest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding the error to your modelstate incorrectly.  You can read more about the ModelStateDictionary on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.addmodelerror(v=vs.118).aspx)

AddModelError takes 2 parameters, so you would want:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Amount", "Greater Than 2 Please.");
```

Having said that, you can use attributes to validate your model properties so you don't have to write all of that code by hand.  Below is an example using the `Range` attribute.  The `RegularExpression` attribute could also work.  Here is an [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.100).aspx) article containing information about the different types of attributes.

```
public class Charity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Range(2, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The value must be greater than 2")]
    public Double Amount { get; set; }
    public Double TaxBonus { get; set; }
    public String Comment { get; set; }
}
```

*Also as a side note, the tutorial you are following is for MVC 1&2.  Unless you HAVE to use / learn that.  I would recommend following the tutorial for MVC 5 [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started)*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and tutorials! , I tried your second approach but a squigly red line appears under "Range" and "ErrorMessage" saying "The type or namespace name " " could not be found.(are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)" , any idea how this can be resolved?

Comment: @john If you're using visual studio you should be able to `ctrl + .` when your cursor is on the squiggly and get a list of the usings to include.  If not, you should just need: `using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Amount, Greater than 2 please");
```

to:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Amount ", "Amount, Greater than 2 please");
```

The first parameter is the member of the model being validated; it can be an empty string just to indicate an error not associated to a field.  By specifying the Amount field, internally it uses that to highlight the erroring field (the control should have input-validation-error CSS class added to it) if you are using all of the client-side validation pieces.

Answer (score 1):

`ModelState.AddModelError` takes 2 arguments, not 1. Link to MSDN [ModelStateDictionary.AddModelError Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.addmodelerror(v=vs.118).aspx).

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Amount", "Greater than 2 please");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (productToCreate.Amount < 2)
    ModelState.AddModelError("Amount", "Greater than 2 please");
```